# Conditional statement in SelectOutput checking for 2 conditions anylogic returning error

Tags: java, anylogic

I am trying to set 2 conditions that have to be checked inside the `Condition` field of `selectOutput`. If the entirety of the first line is false, I want the entirety of the second to be checked. However, using the code below, I am returned the error that only shows for the first instance of `==` of the second statement:

Syntax error on token "==", invalid AssignmentOperator

```
agent.isMorning == true && doctorMorning.idle() == 0;

agent.isMorning == false && doctorAfternoon.idle() == 0;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can package conditions into nested conditions as below:
[image]

Now the agent will continue on the "true" exit if the entire first line is `true`, else it will check the third line and follow whatever boolean that returns.

NOTE: You cannot use `;` in these 1-line condition code boxes. If you want to write longer code, you must create a function that returns a boolean and call that instead. Especially for complex nested statements like yours, it is often much easier to create a specific function

Comment: Apologies, I have edited the question for clarity. I meant the entirety of the first line should be checked to be true. If not, then the entirety of the second line is checked to be true.

Comment: see my edited reply :)

Comment: PS: You can easily shorten the code itself, btw. But this is the most readable, imo ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since Java supports lazy evaluations, this should do what you want:

```
(agent.isMorning && doctorMorning.idle() == 0) || (!agent.isMorning && doctorAfternoon.idle() == 0)
```